# How to check if username is valid on a ssh server

Tags: ssh, dynamic-ip

How can I check if a username exists at a ssh server address using command line tools? For example, I would love to type,

```
isvaliduser [username] [ssh_server]
result: True
```

where `isvaliduser` is some magical function that tests whether a user with name `username` exists at `ssh_server`. But is this feasible?

**My specific application:** The remote server I need to access has a dynamic IP (I can't use a Dynamic DNS service). I can come up with a list of server addresses that contains my target address, but I need a way to figure out which one is mine. I thought one way of doing this would be to test if any of the addresses have the user `myusername`. But if you have another suggestion for solving my particular problem, I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: The best way to do this is a dynamic DNS service, where a program running on the server updates a DNS record with its own IP.

Comment: @DarkFalcon Unfortunately a dynamic DNS service is not an option for me

Comment: Neither is finding out a username is valid on a server unless you also wish to attempt to log into the server, which may be a security risk depending on how you intend to do it. You'll certainly need to provide more info than just the username.

Comment: Keep in mind that ssh servers are designed to not be able to reveal valid user names unless you also supply the proper credentials (password) to log in.

Comment: @nos  is there a way I could test whether the user and password combination is valid, using a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to connect to that server and check if the user is in the `passwd` for example:

```
ssh your_account_at_serve@[ssh_server] grep [username] /etc/passwd
```

If you would be able to enumerate users without authentication, it is considered as a information disclosure and security threat.

Comment: Thanks, I think this should work. Would I be exposing myself to a security vulnerability by using this method? That is, if I attempt to log in to a ssh server using my username and password, would a person at the other end be able to record the name and password I've tried to use?

Comment: No. If you have one account you can log in, you can check the other accounts this way without any security issue.